# system verilog concatenation using values in a variable (type logic)

Tags: system-verilog

In system verilog, variables cannot be used as replication constants. Is there any other way to replicate. I need something like:

```
        logic [7:0] value;
        logic [4:0] full;
        logic [4:0] data_len;


         always_comb begin
            N= full - data_len  ;    
            output = {N{value}};
          end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your case 'full-data_len' can only be 0 or 1 due to the one-bit declaration.  '0' makes no sense in replication, '1' does not need any replication. Please provide a realistic example which can be simulated.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenations can only handle fixed width expressions. You can do this with a *for*-loop:

```
always_comb begin
              N= full - data_len  ;
              output = '0;
              for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                output |= value << i * $bits(value);
            end
```